# using ajax in a symfony project to delete item

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, twig

hello I'm looking for a script that could allow me to delete item in a symfony project using ajax, I didn't find any solution for this I tried to delete an item  via id (I gave a static id) and then get the result without refreshing the page 
here is my controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$evenement = $em->getRepository("TunisiaMallBundle:Evenement")->find(39);
$em->remove($evenement);
$em->flush();
$evenements = $em->getRepository("TunisiaMallBundle:Evenement")->findAll();
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->setContent(json_encode($evenements));
return $response;
```

I didn't know what I'm I supposed to return too.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdvdG.png)

Comment: This depends on your Javascript structure - if you post an AJAX request and depend on an answer (probably to show a success message or reload the page), you should return whatever you want to return. And if you do not depend on anything, just return an empty `JsonResponse` (which is anyways better than setting `application/json` on a raw response)

Comment: if I return an empty json response and I simply want to show the result without refreshing the page ( I included a screenshot of the table, I want to delete that item with ajax.

Comment: So, do so. The posted code will work, you should only inject the ID of the model to be deleted using your request

Comment: I don't know what to write in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your twig put something like this :

```
<button class="deleteBtn" id="{{ item.id }}">Remove</button>
```

Here is the ajax using JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.deleteBtn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    itemId = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({

        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: {'entityId':itemId},
        method: 'post',
        success: function (data, reponse) {

         if(reponse == 'good' ){
            //appear pop to say success blabla
         }
        },
        error: function () {
            //appear pop to say error blabla
        },
    });

});
```

And the Controller :

```
public function ajaxDeleteItemAction(Request $request)
{

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $id = $request->get('entityId');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $evenement = $em->getRepository("TunisiaMallBundle:Evenement")->find($id);

       $em->remove($evenement);
       $em->flush();


    return new JsonResponse('good');
  }
}
```